# Data does not update in view

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic-framework, mean-stack

I am creating an update function in my ionic 4 frontend which has a form to update user info. When I try to change the name, for example, it is updated in the database but is not displayed in the view through interpolation unless I logout and log back in. Here is my update method in the frontend.

```
updateInfo() {
    if (!this.updateForm.valid) {
      this.invalidUpdate();
    } else {

      if (!(this.name === "")) {
        var nameObj = {
          name: this.name
        };
        this._userService.updateName(nameObj).subscribe(
          data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.getUserNamePoints();
          },
          error => {
            this.updateFail();
          }
        );
      }


      };

      this.getUserNamePoints();

    }
  }
```

And here is the method `updateName(name)` in the service

```
updateName(name) {


       var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append(
          "Authorization",
          "Bearer " + this._authService.getAuthorizationToken()
        );
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return this.http
          .post(environment.apiUrl + "/user/updateName", name, {
            headers
          })
          .map(res => res.json());
      }
```

This is the method `getUserNamePoints()` which is also called in the constructor:

```
getUserNamePoints() {
    this._authService.getPoints().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.current = res.data;
      this.clientName = res.name;
    });
  }
```

And here is the interpolation I am performing:

```
  <h2>
    <ion-text color="secondary" style="font-weight:bold">
      Hello, {{ clientName }}!</ion-text
    >
  </h2>
```

This is my backend method:

```
module.exports.updateName = function(req, res, next) {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.decodedToken.user._id,
    {
      $set: req.body
    },
    { new: true }
  ).exec(function(err, updatedUser) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    res.status(200).json({
      err: null,
      msg: "Name was updated successfully.",
      data: req.decodedToken.user.name
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: You're getting the updated name (getUserNamePoints()) immediately after you're **sent** the request to update the name. Call it **after** you know that the request has been processed, i.e. inside the callback receiving the response from the update. Otherwise, you have no guarantee that the get request is not processed before, or concurrenty, to the update request.

Comment: @JBNizet I am calling the method getUserNamePoints() within the callback:  `this._userService.updateName(nameObj).subscribe(
          data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.getUserNamePoints();
          },
          error => {
            this.updateFail();
          }
        ); `

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your backend. I can see that you are sending the data from the decoded token and the token is encoded when you login, so it does not have the updated data.

```
res.status(200).json({
  err: null,
  msg: "Name was updated successfully.",
  data: req.decodedToken.user.name
});
```

Can you show me how are you retrieving the data of the user from your backend when you call the method "getUserNamePoints();" ? Are you looking for the user data in your database or in the decoded token?